# Javascript Regular Expression Problem

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

```
str = 'autocomplete=\\\"off\\\" name=\\\"composer_session_id\\\" value=\\\"1557423901\\\" \\\/>\\u003cinput type=\\\"hidden\\\" autocomplete=\\\"off\\\" name=\\\"is_explicit_place\\\" id=\\\"u436754_5\\\"';
```

or use this string

```
session_id\":1557423901,\"include_source\":\"web_composer\",\"allow_cities\":true},\"bootstrapEndpoint\":\"\\\/ajax\\\/places\\\/typeahead.php\"});},\"j4e8191ff7ff1878042874292\":function(){return new Typeahead(JSCC.get('j4e8191ff7ff1878042874291'), {node_id: \"u436754_1\",
```

i want that `str.match()` return value of `composer_session_id` which is "1557423901" and also the `id` of `is_explicit_plac` which is "u436754_5".

How to get "1557423901" and "u436754_5" using JavaScript `regex.match() or split or else`?

Note: It's guaranteed that `name` will precede `value` in each case.

Comment: Why do you need `match` for this? Seems `split` is better suited here, merely split on `id=` and `value=`.

Comment: will be easier to from this string

Comment: session_id\":1557423901,\"include_source\":\"web_composer\",\"allow_cities\":true},\"bootstrapEndpoint\":\"\\\/ajax\\\/places\\\/typeahead.php\"});},\"j4e8191ff7ff1878042874292\":function(){return new Typeahead(JSCC.get('j4e8191ff7ff1878042874291'), {node_id: \"u436754_1\"

Comment: i need session_id and node_id values which are 1557423901 and u436754_1 respectivly. use any function , i just want these value

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript doesn't have lookbehinds, I wrote this snippet that matches `'attribute=\\\"value\\\"'` then removes the `'attribute=\\\"` and `\\\"` parts.

```
var matches = str.match(/(?:name|id|value)=\\".*?\\"/g);
for (var key in matches)
    matches[key]=matches[key].replace(/.*?\\"(.*?)\\"/,"$1");
```

Enjoy!